# C void* function pointer argument

Tags: c, function-pointers

I'm trying to create a task queue in the ARM. The basic idea is the following.

```
typedef void (*funcpointer)(void *);     // the argument being passed will be a void pointer that I can hopefully typecast

struct sQueue{
   funcpointer       func_address;        // this stores the address of the function to be called
   void              *func_parameter;                   // this stores the address of the struct that is passed to the function
   uint32_t          TimeStamp;                  // the time at which the function should be called     
};

sQueue Func_List[10];
```

The plan is to be able to put the address of the function that should be called in Func_List[x].func_address.

I would like to be able to put the address of functions that accept pointers to different struct types in func_address.
Here's an example:

```
void Config_ADC(sADC_Settings *pSettings);

void Enable_RX(sRX_Top_Settings *pSettings);
```

Both functions accept effectively a 32-bit pointer to a struct, but in these cases the structs are of different types.

When I try to assign Func_List[x].func_address = Config_ADC the compiler complains:

a value of type "void (*)(sADC_Settings *)" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "funcpointer"

Any ideas on how I can achieve this? I can of course change the function Config_ADC to accept a void* pointer and then typecast it inside the function, but I don't really want to do that.

Answer (score 2):

IIRC it is UB to call a function through a function pointer with a different signature.

You will need a proxy function for each non matching function type.

```
void Config_ADC(sADC_Settings *pSettings);
void Config_ADC_proxy(void *pSettings){
  Config_ADC((sADC_Settings*) pSettings);
}
```

Comment: Funnily enough it seems to work with Func_List[0].func = (funcpointer)Config_ADC; The new problem is that Config_ADC is actually a member function of a class and when I try to do Func_List[1].func = (funcpointer)DrvRX1.Config_ADC; I get the error "a pointer to a bound function may only be used to call the function", this is expected as it must know the THIS pointer when calling the function, is there anyway around this?

Comment: @EoinOConnell It is stil undefined behaviour. You are telling the compiler to cast the function pointer you have to another type, but you will still be calling through a pointer of different type.

Comment: `C` doesn't have the concept of member functions. Please add a new question with the `C++` tag. I would avoid to extend this question since it covers a completel different topic. Additionally the question is not the next target of close since it's been answer many times before. The best approach is to search and find something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23184662/call-member-function

Answer (score 1):

A solution is to cast the void pointer inside the function:

```
void Config_ADC(void *p)
{
    sADC_Settings *pSettings = (sADC_Settings *)p;
```

(Actually I don't like this because it unnecesarilly takes up another variable, however, I think it is already better than proxy functions that involve stack management and call management overhead. The compiler shouldn't bother when `void *` is involved; then there would be no overhead at all.)

Comment: You assume here, that he can still change the Config_ADC functions. If that is not the case he HAS to use proxy functions to be UB free.

Answer (score 0):

Your particular [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) specification (specific to the target processor, the operating system, and perhaps even the compiler) dictates how C functions are called and with which [calling conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Calling_convention). Beware that some formal arguments may get passed thru some hardware registers.

I suggest to use `typedef`-s to define any signature of functions called thru pointers:

```
typedef void myroutofint_t(int);
typedef int  myintof2int_t (int, int);
```

If you are sure of the signature of the called function and if you can list all the signatures of functions called thru a pointer, you could use an unamed union (in C99 or C11):

```
struct sQueue{
 enum functiontype_en funtype;
 union {
   void* funaddress;
   myroutofint_t *funroutofint;
   myintof2int_t *funintof2int;
 };
 // othe fields of SQueue
 };
```

The C standard does not even require that function pointers and data pointers live in the same address space and have same size. But POSIX does, and we assume that.

BTW, you might need [libffi](https://sourceware.org/libffi/).